# What does this symbol mean <> in conditional statement in PHP?

Tags: php

Looking at the first condition   //if ($_REQUEST["string"]<>''). What does <> this symbol mean? This is my first time to see one of this. Could someone explain what it is.. Thanks in advance

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'') {
    $search_string = " AND (full_name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR email LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')"; 
}
if ($_REQUEST["city"]<>'') {
    $search_city = " AND city='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["city"])."'";   
}

if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."' AND to_date <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
} else if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
} else if ($_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE to_date <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0".$search_string.$search_city;
}

$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
?>
```

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Thanks, but you should really do more effort on your own, going on stackoverflow for such easy questions is a bit... unusual.  I was able to find the answer despite not even being a php developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have google it once you'll probably get the answer comparatively then over SO

It stands for **NOT EQUAL**

and same as that of **!=**

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate you effort.

Answer (score 0):

It's `not equal to`

Its the same as:

```
if($a != $b){}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Thanks you so much.. I thought it was define by the author..